# Assign forms to form variable and then modify it control

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I windows application and I have multiple similar design form with the same controls name I try to all let say :

```
form2.textbox2.text="somthing"
form3.textbox2.text="somthing"
form4.textbox2.text="somthing"
```

I can't do that, but is another way to do something like:

```
dim formx as form = form2
formx.textbox2.text="something"
formx=form3
formx.textbox2.text="something"
formx=form4
formx.textbox2.text="something"
```

Comment: Create an interface for the forms that have that common need.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a helper method that receives the form, a control name, and a value to set.  Then you can search for the control with [Controls.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find?view=netframework-4.5.2&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection.Find);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    SetText(Me, TextBox1, "Hello")
    SetText(Form2, TextBox2, "World")
    SetText(Form3, TextBox2, "blah")
End Sub

Private Sub SetText(ByVal frm As Form, ByVal controlName As String, ByVal value As String)
    Dim ctl As Control = frm.Controls.Find(controlName, True).FirstOrDefault
    If Not IsNothing(ctl) Then
        ctl.Text = value
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very match  idle_mind I will try it